# look for a way to conbine 0xa5 and 0x9c to 0xa59c

Tags: java

To conbine 2 byte into a short:

```
/* combine 0xa5 and 0x9c to 0xa59c */                                                                                                                 
public class Unsigned
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        byte a = (byte) 0xa5;
        byte b = (byte) 0x9c;
        //int c = ((a&0xff)*256)&0xffff+(b&0xff); // 0
        //int c = a*256+b; // ffffa49c
        int c = (int)a*256+(int)b; // ffffa49c
        System.out.printf("%4x\n", c);
    }
}
```

Why they are all incorrect?

====

The workable version:

```
/* combine 0xa5 and 0x9c to 0xa59c */                                                                                                                 
public class Unsigned
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        byte a = (byte) 0xa5;
        byte b = (byte) 0x9c;
        //int c = ((a&0xff)*256)&0xffff+(b&0xff); // 0
        //int c = a*256+b; // ffffa49c
        //int c = (a&0xff)*256+(b&0xff); // a59c
        int c = ((a & 0xFF )<< 8) | (b & 0xFF);  // a59c
        System.out.printf("%4x\n", c);
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "incorrect"? What do you expect to happen? What's actually happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is this:

```
int c = ((a & 0xFF )<< 8) | (b & 0xFF);
```

Comment: Applying a bit-shift before clearing the 8 LSB's will just clear the `a` value completely. You must switch the operations.

Comment: You were absolutely right. I was a bit silly and got my and and shift the wrong way round. Tested now and it works correctly.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to use bitwise arithmetic instead of multiplications. And in order to avoid sign extensions from converting a byte to an int (both are signed), you can apply a bitmask for the first, least significant, 8 bits. In code:

```
int a_byte = ((int)a & 0xFF);
int b_byte = ((int)b & 0xFF);
int c = (a_byte << 8) | b_byte;
```

A sum instead of a bitwise OR would also work here without any consequences. The explicit conversions to int can also be omitted in this case.

To answer the actual question: the values you inserted were actually negative (over 0x7F). The result of the convertion of both to ints kept the negative sign, which sets all the additional 24 bits to 1. This certainly affected the result.

Answer (score 1):

`System.out.printf("%x\n",(short)((a << 8) | (0xff & b)));`

Cast it to `short` to get 2 bytes and not `ffffa59c`

Shift left to keep a5 and `OR` with `0xff&b` (which is `0xff9c` so when you `OR` you keep the `a5`)